# NameError: name 'finalPdf' is not defined

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, data-driven-pages, nameerror

Could you please help me with this error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DDPeX\Export_GroupPDF.py", line 19, in 
    finalPdf.appendPages(tempPdf)
NameError: name 'finalPdf' is not defined
Failed to execute (CFAsGroupDDP).**

```
import arcpy
import os
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
ddp_lyr = mxd.dataDrivenPages.indexLayer
pdf_field = "CFA"

#Get a list of unique values to group by
pdf_list = set([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ddp_lyr,pdf_field)])

for pdfName in pdf_list:
    finalPdf = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(os.path.join(output_folder,pdfName + ".pdf"))
    for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
        mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
        cur = str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.getValue(pdf_field))
        if cur == pdfName:
            tempPdf = os.path.join(output_folder,"temp_" + cur + str(i) + ".pdf")
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, tempPdf)
            finalPdf.appendPages(tempPdf)
            os.remove(tempPdf)
            finalPdf.saveAndClose()
            del finalPdf, tempPdf
```

Comment: Perhaps include a `print pdf_list' on the line after you set it to make sure that it is what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You are deleting your **finalPdf** before you finishing looping through the data driven pages. Move the delete statement to the same level as the range loop.

```
for i in range(....):
   #do stuff

del finalPdf
```

Comment: Or just get rid of it entirely since it doesn't really do anything: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1478134/386205